# What's the difference among these sentences in meaning?

Tags: difference

Look at these below sentences:

> Rain falling on the roof is making a noise.
>
> Rain falling on the roof makes a noise.
>
> Rain falls on the roof is making a noise.
>
> Rain falls on the roof makes a noise.

1. What's the difference among these sentences in meaning?
2. Are they all correct?

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at these sentences:

> Rain falling on the roof is making a noise.

This is an observation about a particular instance in which the rain is making a certain noise. You are saying that there's a specific sound caused by this rain. You could also say: ***The*** rain falling on the roof is making a noise.

> Rain falling on the roof makes a noise.

This is a general observation about how rain makes noise when it falls on a rooftop. It's not describing a particular time, because rain does not have the definite article ***the***.

> Rain falls on the roof is making a noise.
>
> Rain falls on the roof makes a noise.

These two sentences are grammatically incorrect. They are considered "run-on senteces," because you have to use the conjunction "and" to join two phrases together. For example: *Rain falls on the roof **and** is making a noise.* You can read about run-on sentences here: https://academicguides.waldenu.edu/writingcenter/grammar/runonsentences

Comment: But why can't I say "rain which is falling on the roof is making a noise instead of "rain falling on the roof is making a noise.

Comment: Hi @kuldeepsharma, you can say ***The rain, which is falling on the roof,...***

Or better: ***Rain that's falling on the roof***

Comment: When you use "which," it implies specific rain, so it sounds better to use the definite article ***The***